# Adding ManyToMany related object on the fly in django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Let's say i have two models like those:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField('Property name', max_length=200)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug= slugify(self.name)
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name',max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField('Description')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Pub date',default=datetime.now())
    properties = models.ManyToManyField(Property, blank=True)
```

When i create a new Thing, I'd like to be able to create new related properties, if they don't already exist.

Like, on an ipotetically "ThingForm.save()", i want to iterate through all the properties selected, create the ones which not exist and link them to the new Thing

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your exact requirements are not clear to me.
Can you select properties (by name) that don't exist yet and then create the properties and assign these newly created properties to a (potentially new) thing or do you want to assign properties to a thing that weren't linked to the thing before?

Comment: I think OP means the former.

Comment: I can't recall it anymore, it's been 2 years lol

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can create new properties and link them to a Thing afterwards:

```
# assuming you have a list of names of the selected properties
selected_properties = ['name_1', 'name_2']

for prop_name in selected_properties:
    property, created = Property.objects.get_or_create(name=prop_name)
    # assuming you already have a Thing instance (thing) to attach the properties to ...
    thing.properties.add(property)
```